# Airflow jinja templating: Get param or else execution date (ds_nodash)

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

In my template (XXX.sql) I have:

```
{{ params.etl_date if params.etl_date is not none else execution_date.strftime('%Y%m%d') }}
```

Then in my BigQueryOperator:

```
BigQueryOperator(task_id='XXX',
                 bigquery_conn_id=GOOGLE_CLOUD_PLATFORM_CONNECTION_ID,
                 write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
                 create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
                 sql='XXX.sql',
                 schema=None,
                 use_legacy_sql=False,
                 destination_dataset_table=XXX,
                 params={
                   'etl_date': '20200605'
                 })
```

it works but with:

```
BigQueryOperator(task_id='XXX',
                 bigquery_conn_id=GOOGLE_CLOUD_PLATFORM_CONNECTION_ID,
                 write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
                 create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
                 sql='XXX.sql',
                 schema=None,
                 use_legacy_sql=False,
                 destination_dataset_table=XXX,
                 # NO PARAMS
                 )
```

I can seem to access and format the execution date? It just returns an empty string. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Sergiy's response, it depends on where you want to make your intervention. Sergiy's is the only way for it to work with your template:

```py
{{ params.etl_date if params.etl_date is not None else execution_date.strftime('%Y%m%d') }}
```

The reason why you have to provide it in this case as expressly `None` is owing to the the safe way your template is interpreted and rendered. That is there is an equivalent to `dictionary.get(key, "")` underneath `params.etl_date`... simply because this is safe when building string or text templates.

What you may want to do is use this expressly and change your template to be:

```py
{{ params.etl_date if params.etl_date else execution_date.strftime('%Y%m%d') }}
```

This is because the empty string returned by default by `params.etl_date` will be evaluated by Python to be `False`.

Comment: As you rightly point out in the title... >> this should work ```{{ params.etl_date if params.etl_date else ds_nodash }}```

Answer (score 1):

In the second case you can set:

```
params={ 'etl_date': None}
```